# Unhandled Promise Rejection: SyntaxError: The string did not match the expected pattern in ReactJS Website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I'm building a website using ReactJS that uses JSON present locally on my computer to fetch the information to be filled out. Here is the index.js file: -

```
import React from 'react';
import data from 'notes.json';

class BlogList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state={
            items:[],
            loaded: false
    };

}

/* useEffect()=>{
return function(){

}
},[deep])
*/      //Similar to ComponentDidUnMount();

componentDidMount(){
    fetch(data)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
        this.setState({
            items: json,
            loaded: true,
        })
    })
    
 }

    render() {
        const {items, loaded} = this.state;

       if(!loaded){
            return <h3>Loading........</h3>
        }
        return (
            <div className="content-container" >
            {   
                items.map((item)=>(
                    <div key={item.id}>

                        <p>
                            {item.postId}
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            {item.id}
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            {item.name}
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            {item.email}
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            {item.body}
                        </p>
                        <hr/>
                    </div>
                ))

            }
        </div>
        );
    }
}

export default BlogList;
```

And the JSON file is here: -

```
[
  {
    "postId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "name": "id labore ex et quam laborum",
    "email": "Eliseo@gardner.biz",
    "body": "laudantium enim quasi est quidem magnam voluptate ipsam eos\ntempora quo necessitatibus\ndolor quam autem quasi\nreiciendis et nam sapiente accusantium"
  },
  {
    "postId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "name": "quo vero reiciendis velit similique earum",
    "email": "Jayne_Kuhic@sydney.com",
    "body": "est natus enim nihil est dolore omnis voluptatem numquam\net omnis occaecati quod ullam at\nvoluptatem error expedita pariatur\nnihil sint nostrum voluptatem reiciendis et"
  },
  {
    "postId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "name": "odio adipisci rerum aut animi",
    "email": "Nikita@garfield.biz",
    "body": "quia molestiae reprehenderit quasi aspernatur\naut expedita occaecati aliquam eveniet laudantium\nomnis quibusdam delectus saepe quia accusamus maiores nam est\ncum et ducimus et vero voluptates excepturi deleniti ratione"
  },
  {
    "postId": 1,
    "id": 4,
    "name": "alias odio sit",
    "email": "Lew@alysha.tv",
    "body": "non et atque\noccaecati deserunt quas accusantium unde odit nobis qui voluptatem\nquia voluptas consequuntur itaque dolor\net qui rerum deleniti ut occaecati"
  }
]
```

It is constantly giving me this error in the console: - Unhandled Promise Rejection: SyntaxError: The string did not match the expected pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may get this error if the server's response is text but you attempt to parse it as JSON using res.json().

```
fetch(serverUrl, {method: 'GET'})
.then((res) => res.json())
res.text()
```

is appropriate if the server returns text.

In this situation Safari once gave me the OP's error, but Chrome was more specific: "unexpected token W in json at position 0" -- res.json() expects the first character of the string to be { or [ since that is how JSON begins.

Or, as Safari would say, "the string did not match the expected pattern."

Comment: Thanks, now it gives me the following error: -   Line 25:5:  'res' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: change res to the name of the variable you have written in .then((response)=> {}) callback

Comment: Does this seem good: -
componentDidMount(){
    fetch(data, {method: 'GET'})
    .then((response) => response.json())
     response.text() 
    .then(json => {
        this.setState({
            items: json,
            loaded: true
        })
    })
    
 }

Comment: Yes, Hopefully it will work.

Comment: Line 25:6:  'response' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: Please check the Network tab for the browser that what you are getting back from the server, and debug the promise function if you are using it correctly. There is some issue with your code logic now. The original question is answered.

Comment: Right. I'll check it. Thanks for your help! Also does the code above seem correct to you?

Comment: Can you accept the answer or vote it so that it can be closed?

Comment: If you can help, I'll be highly obliged!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242485/discussion-between-prubhtej-singh-and-kael).

Comment: I can help you learning React too, please share your Skype. I will add you there.

Answer (score 0):

For those people getting this error from reading a json file from the local or public folder make sure the file path is preceded correctly. If there is no initial "/" in the file name it's looking at current directory and it may not find the json file. So, instead of:

```
fetch("data.json")
```

try:

```
fetch("/data.json")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using ReactJs and your json file is local, just move the json file to public folder of your ReactJs app and it will fix it with proper referencing