# Stripe error: The string did not match the expected pattern

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

i have a problem with stripe, i create a token with stripe js, then i add token's response in this card and i add this token to a connect account, but its run successfull in web, but the mobile use webview to do it and sometime its return error `The string did not match the expected pattern`.
What should I do when I do it on the web and it works, but on mobile I use webview and it sometimes returns an error?
This is my code js:

```
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_51ObgQ7AapkrJHjBL5v8QlnwtO6ARkY0cjR1PQHdol7DHzvwMnfHp7yJo44O1uMoAu17hotn4NOaI6FITTVH84auC00Cq4IfMCd');
var elements = stripe.elements();

var card = elements.create('card', {
    style: {
        base: {
            iconColor: '#666EE8',
            lineHeight: '40px',
            fontFamily: '-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif',
            fontSize: '15px',

            '::placeholder': {
                color: '#CFD7E0',
            },
        },
    }
});
card.mount('#card-element');

function setOutcome(result) {
    var successElement = document.querySelector('.success');
    var errorElement = document.querySelector('.error');
    successElement.classList.remove('visible');
    errorElement.classList.remove('visible');

    if (result.token) {
        // Use the token to create a charge or a customer
        // https://stripe.com/docs/charges
        // successElement.querySelector('.token').textContent = result.token.id;
        var token = result.token.id;
        fetch("/stripe/card/processing", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ token }),
        }).then((r) => {
            if (r.ok) {
                setLoading(false);
                var successElement = document.querySelector('.success');
                successElement.textContent = "Success! Your Stripe card was successfully processed";
                successElement.classList.add('visible');
            }
            return r.json();
        }).catch((error) => {
            setLoading(false);
            errorElement.textContent = error.message;
            errorElement.classList.add('visible');
        });
    } else if (result.error) {
        setLoading(false);
        errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
        errorElement.classList.add('visible');
    }
}

card.on('change', function (event) {
    setOutcome(event);
});

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', async function (e) {
    setLoading(true);
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = document.querySelector('form');
    var extraDetails = {
        name: form.querySelector('input[name=cardholder-name]').value,
        currency: 'usd',
    };
    stripe.createToken(card, extraDetails).then(setOutcome);
});

// Show a spinner on payment submission
function setLoading(isLoading) {
    if (isLoading) {
        document.querySelector("#submit").disabled = true;
        document.querySelector("#spinner").classList.remove("hidden");
        document.querySelector("#button-text").classList.add("hidden");
    } else {
        document.querySelector("#submit").disabled = false;
        document.querySelector("#spinner").classList.add("hidden");
        document.querySelector("#button-text").classList.remove("hidden");
    }
}
```

this is function of `/stripe/card/processing`:
[image]
Here is an error:
[image]

i dont know what i should do, because web is successfull and webview sometime error .

Note: Mobile i use webview (not browser with mobile device - responsive)

Comment: are you sure the error is coming from Stripe and isn't being returned by your code? Are you finding any relevant API errors for this in your log? https://support.stripe.com/questions/finding-the-id-for-an-api-request

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unhandled Promise Rejection: SyntaxError: The string did not match the expected pattern in ReactJS Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71295120/unhandled-promise-rejection-syntaxerror-the-string-did-not-match-the-expected)